# Why can't I use probability of an intersection to check whether events are independent

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

I have to test whether two events are independent. I want to do this by checking whether P(A)P(B)=P(A and B), but I've been told that's not valid in the context, and I need to use P(A|B)=P(A). I don't understand why these two equations aren't equivalent statements. Context below:

"Records kept by a canteen in a business centre show that 62% of its customers work in sales. 75% of the customers who work in sales order fruit with their meal, whilst for other customers the figure is 55%.

Explain whether the records indicate that working in sales and ordering fruit with a meal are independent events."

I understand that I can check whether P(S|F)=P(S), but I don't understand why I can't check whether P(S)P(F)=P(S and F). Please help!

Comment: The only difference I know is the situation where $P(B)=0$, and one of those equations will suffer a divide by zero. That's why the definition of independence uses the other equation - you don't have to add an "unless..." to the definition. Independence w.r.t. a zero probability event has always struck me as pretty meaningless anyways, and if you always check that you're not dividing by zero it should be the same, but some instructors do like to give a rule that had absolutely no exceptions.

Comment: You can. P(S)P(F)=P(S)P(F|S). It turns out to check  if $P(F)=P(F|S)$

Comment: Thank you, this is very reassuring. It's my head of department who says otherwise, soi needed some reassurance!